# How to authenticate the other webpage while opening via Iframe aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I want to show our company internal site in my custom page.

In my **aspx** page added **Iframe** tag and wants to show the internal site in the **iframe** tag.

I know the `username` and `password` for the internal site.

When I open my **aspx** page its asking for user credential **popup** for internal site,

How to provide the user credentials in `web.config` part or is there any best way to bypass user authentication popup?

Any suggestions ?